# for loop string line by line not letter by letter

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string where I words on each line. Im trying to write a for loop to print each word by word or line by line.

```
String = 
"Hello
 How
 Are
 you"


for x in String:
    print(x)
```

Sadly im getting

```
H
e
l
l
o

H
o
w

A
r
e

Y
o
u
```

Instead of this?

```
Hello
How
Are
You
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Nothing went wrong. It is a `string of characters` which you're iterating over. If you want to `split` your text into `lines`, use `String.splitlines()` and iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is something like this?

```
String =  "Hello How Are you"

for x in String.split(' ') :
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the string split function to split the string by space character or endofline character( \n )

```
string = "Mama \n are \n mere"
splitstring = string.split("\n")
for x in splitstring:
    print(x)
```

OR

```
string = "Mama are mere"
splitstring = string.split(" ")
for x in splitstring:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Read about this: 
Separator   ---  Specifies the separator to use when splitting the string. By default any whitespace is a separator

Also, to note: the way you are doing it, you are accessing your string as an array of characters (not words).  Therefore for each character in your string you are getting an output.